# how to put burger icon to it's first place after closing menu

Tags: javascript, css

I have a sidebar and when I click on the burger icon it should get a margin:35% but I want it to get back to it's first place when I close the menu

```
(function () {
  'use strict'
    document.querySelector('[data-bs-toggle="offcanvas"]').addEventListener('click', 
    function () {
      document.querySelector('.offcanvas-collapse').classList.toggle('open')
   })})()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle("change");
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1, .bar2, .bar3 {
  width: 35px;
  height: 5px;
  background-color: #333;
  margin: 6px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}

.change .bar2 {opacity: 0;}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
  <div class="bar1"></div>
  <div class="bar2"></div>
  <div class="bar3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I mean the burger icon. I want the burger icon to get back

Comment: it just got fixed؟?